# PHP Carbon date in a for loop in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I want to create loan payment schedule for six months so i want to increment one month from today up to 6 times and save it to db

This is what I tried till now:

```php
$date = Corbon::now();    

for($i=0;$i<$request->duration;$i++) {
    $newDate=$date->addMoth();
    $schedule = new LoanSchedual(['dueDate' => $newDate]);
    $loan->loanSchedules()->save($schedule);
}
```

So that I got this

> 2016-10-18
>   2016-11-18
>   2016-12-18
>   2017-1-18
>   2016-10-18...etc

Comment: I don't get the question, would you please be more explicit on what you need help on? PS: It's `Carbon`, not `Corbon`

Comment: i want to create loan payment schedule for six months so i want to increment one month fro today up to 6 times and save it to db

Answer (score 0):

```
$newDate->subDay()->format('Y-m-d'); //returns something like 2016-10-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you better explained what you need it is easier to understand how to help you.

This should help.

```php
$date = Carbon\Carbon::now();    

for ($i=0; $i < $request->duration; $i++) {
    $newDate = $date->addMoth($i+1);
    $loan->loanSchedules()->create(['dueDate' => $newDate]);
}
```

Comment: Tenks this help

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to select the answer and upvote if it solved your problem